# How to filter items?

Tags: python

I have a method for extracting some values from a text string. But the ordering is now via how many times the word in the list occurrences. And I want to have the ordering via first occurence in text string.

So this is the text:

```
text = """['

E-mail: sales@verdiimport.nl, www.verdiimport.nl Dutch law shall apply. The Rotterdam District Court shall have exclusive jurisdiction.

rut ard wegetables

']"""
```

and this is the filtermethod:

```
def total_fruit_cost(file_name):
    fruit_cost_found = []
    single_fruit = [fruit for fruit in fruit_words]
    #print(single_fruit)
    for fruit in single_fruit:
        m = re.findall(regex_fruit_cost(fruit), file_name)
        if m:
            fruit_cost_found.append(m)   
    return  next(list(item for sublist in fruit_cost_found for item in sublist))
```

and the regex_fruit_cost:

```
def regex_fruit_cost(subst):
    return r"(?<=" + subst + r").*?(?P<number>[0-9,.]*)\n"
```

and the list of fruit_words:

```
fruit_words = ['Appels', 'Ananas', 'Peen Waspeen',
               'Tomaten Cherry', 'Sinaasappels',
               'Watermeloenen', 'Rettich', 'Peren', 'Peen', 'Mandarijnen', 'Meloenen', 'Grapefruit']
```

So the output is now like this:

```
['3.488,16', '137,50', '500,00', '1.000,00', '2.000,00', '1.000,00', '381,25', '123,20', '2.772,00', '46,20', '577,50', '69,30']
```

But it has to be by first occurence: `123.20, 2772,00, 46,20, etc..381,25` because so it occurs in the text string

So that the ordering will be as first occurence, second occurence, etc in the text string.

My question is: what I have to change?

So if you take this text string:

```
verdi49 = "['Ver\n\nFactuur\nVerdi Import Schoolfruit\nFactuur nr; ¢ 71215 Koopliedenweg 38\nDeb. nr, : 108636 2991 LN BARENDRECHT\nYour VAT nr. : NL851703884B01 Nederland\nFactuur datum : 13-12-21\nAantal Omschrijving Prijs Bedrag\nOrdernumber’ : 77150 Loading date 02-12-21 Incoterm: : FOT\nYour ref. : SCHOOLFRUIT Delivery date\nWK49\nD.C. Schoolfruit\n612 Peen Breek peen 10x1kg B Rabbit NLI € 4,/0 € 2.876,40\n688 Appels Royal Gala 13kg 60/65 Generica PL I € 4,87 € 3.350,56\n320 Sinaasappels Valencias 15kg 105 FVC ZAI € 6,25 € 2.000,00\n400 Sinaasappels Valencias 15kg 105 FVC ZAI € 6,25 € 2.500,00\n74 Sinaasappels Valencias 15kg 105 FVC ZAI € 6,25 € 462,50\nMidden Zuid Noord\nVerDi Wortel 202 164 246 612\nVerDi Sinaas 262 212 320 794\n\n \n\nTotaal Colli\n\n \n\nGAT — 7\n\noe TUNUMMER 4 |\n\n   \n\nTotaal Bedrag\n\n€ 12.196,51\n\n \n\nBetaling binnen 30 dagen\n\nAchterstand wordt gemeld bij de kredietverzekeringsmaatschappij\n\nVerDi Import BV\n\nKoopliedenweg 38, 2991 LN Barendrecht, The Netherlands\nTel. +31 (0)1 80 61 88 11, Fax +31 (0)1 80 61 88 25\n\nE-mail: sales@verdiimport.nl, www.verdiimport.nl\n\nING Bank N.V, Rotterdam IBAN number: NL17INGBO006959173\nSWIFT/BIC: INGBNL2A, VAT number: NL851703884B01\nChamber of Commerce Rotterdam no. 55424309\n\nOutch law shall apply. The Rotterdam District Court shall have exclusive jurisdiction.\nfrt ard vegetables\n\n \n\x0c']"
```

it also takes this number in the return: 12.196,51. This number has not be included.

So the regex have to be combined with the list of fruit_words

I try it like this:

```
def regex_fruit_cost():
    return r"(?<=" + '|'.join(re.escape(word) for word in fruit_words) + ')' + r").*?(?P<number>[0-9,.]*)\n"
```

But then I get this error:

```
 raise source.error("unbalanced parenthesis")
re.error: unbalanced parenthesis at position 126
```

Thank you of course. But I also tested for this string:

```
verdi9_1 = "['a>)\n\nFactuur\nVerdi Import Schoolfruit\nFactuur nr. : 74658 Koopliedenweg 38\nDeb. nr. : 108636 2991 LN BARENDRECHT\nYour VAT nr. : NL851703884B01 Nederland\nFactuur datum : 24-02-22\nAantal Omschrijving Prijs Bedrag\nOrder number : 81305 Loading date : 24-02-22 Incoterm: : FRA\nYour ref. : SCHOOLFRUIT Delivery date\nWwkKO9\nD.C. Schoolfruit\n262 Peren Conference 12kg 55/60 GENER NL II € 5,28 € 1.383,36\n120 Grapefruit Rio Red 14kg 35-OT Tekasya TR I € 10,50 € 1.260,00\n28 Grapefruit Rio Red 14kg 36-OT Tuval TRI € 10,50 € 294,00\n39 Grapefruit Rio Red 14kg 36-OT Tuval TRI € 10,50 € 409,50\n55 Grapefruit Rio Red 14kg 36-OT Tuval TRI € 10,50 € 577,50\n287 Appels Royal Gala 13kg 60/65 Generica PL I € 5,72 € 1.641,64\nTotaal Colli Totaal Netto Btw Btw Bedrag Totaal Bedrag\n791 € 5.566,00 € 6.066,94\n\n \n\nBetaling binnen 30 dagen\nAchterstand wordt gemeld bij de kredietverzekeringsmaatschappij\n\nING Bank N.V. Rotterdam IBAN number: NL17INGB0006959173\nSWIFT/BIC: INGBNL2A, VAT number: NL851703884B01\n\na\nChamber of Commerce Rotterdam no. 55424309, VerDi\nDutch law shall apply. The Rotterdam District Court shall have exclusive jurisdiction.\n\nfruit and vegetables\n\x0c']"
```

and then the output is:

```
[('Peren', ''), ('Grapefruit', ''), ('Grapefruit', ''), ('Appels', '')]
```

Comment: One way may be to search for all fruits at once by using `'|'.join(fruit_words)` as "subst" in the regex.

Comment: @MichaelButscher. I try it like this: 
def regex_fruit_cost(substr):
    return r"(?<=" + substr + r").*?(?P<number>[0-9,.]*)\n" + '|'.join(re.escape(word) for word in fruit_words) + ')'

Comment: @Anoushiravan R. Do you have a suggestion for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import re

def regex_fruit_cost(subst):
    return rf"(?:{subst}).*?(?P<number>[0-9,.]*)\n"

fruits_groups = (f"(?:{fruit})" for fruit in fruit_words)
fruits_combined_with_capture = f'({"|".join(fruits_groups)})'
fruits_pattern = regex_fruit_cost(fruits_combined_with_capture)
print(re.findall(fruits_pattern,text))
```

You were on the right track but instead of going through the fruits and finding them in order, you can use them in the regex pattern using the `|` character. Try printing the variables I used what strings they produce.

Edit: it also works for your `verdi49` text

Outputs:

```
[('Watermeloenen', '123,20'), ('Watermeloenen', '2.772,00'), ('Watermeloenen', '46,20'), ('Watermeloenen', '577,50'), ('Watermeloenen', '69,30'), ('Appels', '3.488,16'), ('Sinaasappels', '137,50'), ('Sinaasappels', '500,00'), ('Sinaasappels', '1.000,00'), ('Sinaasappels', '2.000,00'), ('Sinaasappels', '1.000,00'), ('Sinaasappels', '381,25')]
```